# Is there a way to capture Nifi API calls that the UI makes?

Tags: apache-nifi

Since the Nifi GUI is really making api calls under the hood, is there anyway to capture those requests or logs? I've been using chrome dev tools. Just wondering if there is a way to capture this within nifi for governance purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome Dev tools is the best bet to get the actual API calls.

For auditing purposes there is something a little bit different... from the menu in the top-right there is "Flow Configuration History" which shows every change that has been made to the flow, and who made it (when in a secure instance).

The flow configuration history is also available through the ReportingTask API if you wanted to implement a custom reporting task to push these events somewhere.

Comment: Each request is also logged in the logs/nifi-app.log.